# OS task scheduling emulator

Tags: c++, c, task, simulation, rtos

I'm trying to find a c or c++ library which is could work with tasks(or threads) in preemptive way. I need a mechanism which could manage tasks one by one like in RTOS. Creating tasks (function as an entry point to a task), timeslicing, switching etc...

Is it possible to write it in a user-space?

Comment: it would be hard without some platform specific stuff, i think.  as far as i know, there is no (C++ specific) mechanism to interrupt a thread as it is executing.  you'd need a timer that does that in order to implement preemption.

Comment: which platform you are using for developing?

Comment: For now (for simulation purpose) it's x86 with linux. real RTOS (i think it will be RTEMS) will be used on ARM.

Comment: You can try Linux scheduling api, like sched_{get,set}scheduler to manipulate task's priority/policy.

Comment: If you're using windows, you can use SetThreadPriority(), but the number of levels of priority is some what limited. For the embedded projects I have worked on in the past, a common limit was 16 threads, each with a different priority (there's no time slicing with this setup).

Comment: FreeRTOS exists in a X86 port that runs atop of pthreads. Consider an approach like that, as it will simulate the concurrency of preemptive multitasking, but of course not schedule deterministically or according to priority etc.

Comment: The comment about RTEMS and ARM are relevant and should be in the question not the comments.  You are in danger of asking an XY problem here,  The question is about your solution rather than your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is perhaps to run a *real* RTOS in a virtual machine or processor emulator.  Any RTOS with an x86 port might be persuaded to run in a PC VM, but you could also use QEMU.

For example you can run [RTEMS on QUEMU](http://www.rtems.org/wiki/index.php/QEMU), and QUEMU itself can emulate ARM targets - though that may not matter and the i386 emulation may suit your needs and will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

RTOS scheduling/dispatching to handle threads in an efficient manner requires hardware interrupts to communicate effectively with peripheral hardware, (KB, mouse, disk, NIC, timer etc).  Standard C has no means of handling interrupts, so you cannot do it.

If you have memory-management hardware that defines separate user and kernel memory access rights, then no - a hardware interrupt will change state in hardware and so you will leave user space whether you want to or not.

You should be aware that preemptive schedulers are not primarily designed to switch between tasks that need CPU upon a timer interrupt - they are designed first to provide efficent, high-performance I/O by removing CPU from tasks that don't need it because their I/O requests cannot be met immediately.